# how to locate syslog on AIX machine

Tags: aix, syslog

I have a machine that does not have the syslog in the usual place. How would I go about locating it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with:

```
man syslogd
```

and go from there.

Or are you saying that `/etc/syslog.conf` is not there.

If it is there, it should be able to tell you where all the log files are. If it's not there, you need to find out how `syslogd` was run, either:

- by looking at its entry from `ps`; or
- looking at the `/etc/rc.d` entry that started it.

Comment: Manual entry for syslog not found or not installed.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Someone had moved the startup into a custom S99others script!?!?